# cannot get the latest item from a range in bash

Tags: bash, travis-ci

I am trying to read the latest commit for the current pull req in Travis. I tried the following

```
echo "Latest commit is: $TRAVIS_COMMIT"
```

But the commit does not seem to be the correct one. So used the following:

```
echo "commit range: ${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE}"
```

and I got:

```
commit range: 76acf3b3b213cd3f4f1e3a023e250ca23072fedd...474b7552e8a605b860df7b353dc8658d5025b0bf
```

So now I need to parse the above range to get only string like:

```
474b7552e8a605b860df7b353dc8658d5025b0bf
```

But when I do this in bash:

```
echo "commit range: ${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE[-1]}"
```

I get:

```
: bad array subscript
```

How can I do that? can anyone help?

Comment: Add output of `declare -p TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE` to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE is not an array, it's a single string.

Try parameter expansion instead:

```
${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE##*.}  # Remove everything up to the last dot
```

- `#` removes the shortest matching pattern from the beginning of the value
- `##` works similarly, but uses the longest matching pattern
- `*.` as a pattern means "anything followed by a dot"

Similarly, `%` removes from the end of a value.

Comment: would this work: echo "${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE##*.}"? (I am trying it)

Comment: worked thanks. Can you explain it a bit for better clarification?